# Direct link to MediaWiki page section

Tags: mediawiki

In my Wikipedia page, I have a section called subtitleA. Before arriving at this point when reading, I have one sentence that has a link that jumps to the content of that section.

To be more clear, this is a simple illustration:

```
To do this, you will need `this` (link to subtitleA).
To do that, you will do another thing..

== SubtitleA ==

this is how you do it....
```

I found the following solution:

```
To do this, you will need [http://wikisite.com/pageName#SubtitleA this].
```

This has already been proven correct; however, one of my subtitles contains spaces, brackets and directory like the following:

```
== SubtitleA (balabalaA\balabalaB\balabala....) ==
```

I can no longer use the solution I found because of those spaces... Can anyone provide me an alternative solutions? Thanks.

Comment: You just need to URL encode the anchor - spaces become `%20`, open paren becomes `%28`, etc.

Comment: @AndrewMedico What if what I have in the parentheses is a directory that has the form 'xxx\yyy\zzz'? The '\' is %5C, but... the website will just become xxx%5Cyyy... how does it recognize that Cyyy is not an entity?

Comment: `**…**` is not a subtitle. `== … ==` is?

Comment: @return0: All [percent-encodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) are two letters. It'll only consider the `5C` part after the `%`.

Comment: The subtitle aka tagline is a totally different thing in MediaWiki. You are talking about sections (or maybe a specific kind of them , like `h2`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
To do this, you will need [[pageName#SubtitleA|this]].
```

Use the exact same format as in the section title.

Anchor encoding is similar to percent encoding (with a `.` instead of a `%`) but not exactly the same (e.g. spaces are collapsed and encoded to `_`). If you really, really need to do it directly, you can use `{{anchorencode|original title}}`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

URL encoder is the key, but not using standard `%xx` as the replacements for special characters. Use `.xx` (e.g. `.5C` `.28`) would work in the mediawiki framework.

Comment: You really should not do the encoding manually. There is an entire manual page on explaining how the encoding is done, you don't want to learn it. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:PAGENAMEE_encoding